# Fatal error: Call to undefined method CRM_Contribute_Task::taskTitles()

Tags: wordpress, civimember, error

Civicrm 4.7.31 on Wordpress
I get this error when attempting to edit a Membership. Initially, I get a blank pop-up with the message "Network Error. Unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page in your browser and try again." I then right clciked on the link and opened it in a new tab and I get the error 
"Fatal error: Call to undefined method CRM_Contribute_Task::taskTitles() in .../www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Task.php on line 163"

At the moment, we are unable to view or edit any memberships so that we can edit them and update details or change the status if members cancel. How do we resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sudesh,

I am not sure if you are using right CiviCRM version. As I can see on 4.7.31 the function does exists and the line number you pointed in your question i.e [163](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/4.7.31/CRM/Contribute/Task.php#L163) is showing me different code.

Please make sure your code base is using 4.7.31 version and since you are using older version of CiviCRM, I would recommend you to upgrade atleast to 5.3.1 because of security issues.